# Calculating bandwidth through time constant method

Tags: time-constant

Given this circuit:

[image]

I'm willing to calculate the cut-off frequencies of this circuit.

C1=2 pF

C2=0.5 pF

C3=40 nF

C4 --> infinity

Can I use the constant time method (both open and short) to approximate the 3 dB frequencies or must I calculate the entire transfer function and find its poles?
As far as I know, the short circuit method works for large capacitors and the open circuit capacitor works for small capacitors. Since I can't clearly decide which capacitor is large and which one is negligible, do I have to take them all into account while calculating the f-high cutoff frequency and f-low calculating frequency?

Comment: You can already separate the stages. The first op-amp in the left can be isolated and there are two poles only, no zeroes. Then, you can calculate the transfer function of the two other cascaded filters separately considering a 0-ohm impedance driving \$C_4\$ and an infinite impedance loading \$R_9\$. It complicates a bit when \$S_1\$ toggles to position \$a\$ though. You can certainly use the FACTs which leads to the exact TF: see my seminar https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

Comment: Just use a simulator.